# Google Maps Javascript API v3 returning different JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm aware of the JSON output format as [given by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON)

However, I'm sometimes getting a [slightly different format](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://hastebin.com/raw/hubifinowa). This is from the `results` variable in the callback function of `gecoder.geocode({'address': address}, callback)`

```
"location": {
          "Za": 37.3492097,
          "$a": -122.03260190000003
        },
```

...

```
"viewport": {
          "aa": {
            "b": 37.329901,
            "f": 37.37543489999999
          },
          "ba": {
            "b": -122.06526500000001,
            "f": -121.99577999999997
          }
        }
```

Notice the keys under location, bounds and viewport - they are different from what's standard. This is a problem for me because I need to send this JSON over <strike>an AJAX call and</strike> to my server and parse it and my parser can't take "$a" as a valid key name.

Is this normal or am I missing something?

EDIT:
I'm on a cloud hosted platform (salesforce.com). We're using the Javascript API v3. I was able to replicate this issue from a local HTML file.
<strike>I'm now thinking it might be because I'm behind a corporate proxy. Anyone faced this before?</strike>

Comment: Why can't your parser take it? It's a valid json key name. Maybe fix your parser?

Comment: Is the "slightly different format" data the result of a correctly-formulated query? What is that query? If you have followed the docs, the results should be consistent.

Comment: The parser I'm using is built into the platform I'm on, expects the key values to be variable names in a class and "$" is not an accepted character

Comment: I'm using the standard geocoder.geocode function provided by GMaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment on the bug report and on the API documentation, the `response` object in the callback is not pure JSON. In order to get a JSON object, I needed to create one myself like below:

```
//assume status is ok

var bestResult = getBestResultFromJSON(results);

var bounds = {'northeast' : {'lat' : 0, 'lng' : 0}, 'southwest' : {'lat' : 0, 'lng' : 0}};
var location = {'lat' : 0, 'lng' : 0};
var viewport = {'northeast' : {'lat' : 0, 'lng' : 0}, 'southwest' : {'lat' : 0, 'lng' : 0}};
// bounds not always available (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry)
if(bestResult.geometry.hasOwnProperty(bounds)) {
    bounds.southwest.lat = bestResult.geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    bounds.southwest.lng = bestResult.geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    bounds.northeast.lat = bestResult.geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    bounds.northeast.lng = bestResult.geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
}
else {
    bounds = null;
}                       

viewport.southwest.lat = bestResult.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat();
viewport.southwest.lng = bestResult.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lng();
viewport.northeast.lat = bestResult.geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lat();
viewport.northeast.lng = bestResult.geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lng();

location.lat = bestResult.geometry.location.lng();
location.lng = bestResult.geometry.location.lng();

var jsonResults = {'results' : [{'address_components' : bestResult.address_components,
              'formatted_address': bestResult.formatted_address,
              'geometry' : {'bounds' : bounds, 'location' : location, 'location_type' : bestResult.location_type, 'viewport' : viewport},
              'types' : bestResult.types}], 'status' : status};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only documented methods and getting a non-documented response, it's a bug. File an issue in the [Issues List](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) -- you will need to include a demonstrator address, if there is one which produces a wrong response consistently. If there isn't a consistently-wrong address, then give as much detail as possible. Does it happen with requests repeated too close together, for example?

Make sure that you also test using a different browser client and maybe even a different machine as well. There could be an oddity in your current browser or computer which is causing the API to misbehave.

I suggest commenting this answer with the issue number for future reference.

Comment: I've filed [bug 4089](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4089)

It seems like, even from Google's Geocoding example page, the responses are not correct. See: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: There's *a lot* more in that report than in the question. Using salesforce.com, https and authentication could all be relevant (it also means that you should have a Maps for Business licence which comes with support direct from Google). Try eliminating each of those three in turn and in combination and seeing if it makes a difference. For example, I don't use https or salesforce.com and have never had a problem like this.

Comment: We aren't using Maps for Business _yet_.
I even created a simple HTML file and got the same. Am thinking now maybe because I'm behind a proxy? Will circle back once I get to try it from a different network